# Haskell GHCI compiler: Parse error in repl when defining and declaring a simple function

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm going through the "Learn You A Haskell" book.

I'm trying to define this simple function but the compiler is spitting it out. It's probably something very basic and simple but I'm a complete Haskell newbie:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> doubleMe x = x + x

<interactive>:2:12: parse error on input `='
```

Prelude>

Comment: You need to use `let` - `let doubleMe x = x + x`.

Comment: Why doesn't he mention it in book? Is this something new in this version of ghci?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [read the book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions) carefully, it says (emphasis mine):

> **Open up your favorite text editor** and punch in this function that takes a number and multiplies it by two.
>
> ```
>     doubleMe x = x + x
> ```

Which is fine for ghc, because it can understand that it's a function declaration (and the book didn't tell you to try it in ghci. In fact, [shortly after](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists) it explains how `let` can be used *"to define a name right in GHCI. Doing let a = 1 inside GHCI is the equivalent of writing a = 1 in a script and then loading it."*). To make ghci understand that you are defining a function you need to use `let`:

```
Prelude> let doubleMe x = x + x
Prelude> doubleMe 10
20
```

Comment: Note: I'm quite illiterate in Haskell, so I don't actually know _why_ there is such a difference.

Comment: @Shabaz - It's because ghci executes in the IO monad, so you need to use let to bind non-IO values.

Comment: One thing I am not liking about Haskell is the REPL. It's like you have to learn all kinds of complex features of Haskell before you even use it.

Comment: @EvanZamir, the REPL is really just for experimenting. So once you know the basics and you want to quickly test how something works, you can use the REPL. You won't miss much though if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

In GHCi, you bind new identifiers using the `let` keyword.

```
> let doubleMe x = x + x
> doubleMe 3
> 6
```